# Find all elements with the same css class in html page embedded in an "object" tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It's a little bit difficult to explain:

I have this code:

```
$("#renderMore1").after("<div class ='hwMore col-xs-12' id = 'hwMore1'></div>");
$("#hwMore1").append('<object id = "monitorHW1" type="text/html" data="http://192.168.2.123:8085/index.html" width="100%"; ></object>');
```

it's a web page (http://192.168.2.123:8085/index.html) inside an object tag, inside a div. 
This page is loaded with a click. 
When the page is loaded I need to look for all items with the same class (child-of-node-1). I tried these    (#renderMore1 is a div):

```
$('#monitorHW1').find('.child-of-node-1').each(function (i, obj) {
    ----code-----
}

$('#monitorHW1' .child-of-node-1').each(function (i, obj) {
    ----code-----
}
```

I post you a screen of an inspection of the page:

[image]

Tell me if I can make this question better...thank you!

**EDIT:**
I tried to select the table (see the img above) and looked for parents but I stopped at "document". It's like the page loaded in "#monitorHW1" isn't a child of that object...

[image]

Comment: You have posted publicly inaccessible IP for URL

Comment: Yes it's a local IP, I don't know how to remove the link, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try using [jQuery children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/). It may look like this.

```
$("#monitorHW1").children(".child-of-node-1");
```

Comment: Hi and thank you! I'm reading the page that you posted, but the code doesn't work....

Answer (score 0):

Use the contents method:

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $("#monitorHW1").contents().find(".child-of-node-1").each(function () {
   //code
   })
});
```

Comment: Hi and thank you! I'm sorry but it doesn't work, it doesn't enter in the loop and if  I try it on the Chrome console, it returns 0 elements...

Answer (score -1):

Normal CSS Selectors in `document.querySelectorAll` should work fine

```
<object>
   <div class="test">

   </div>
   <div class="test">

   </div>
   <div class="test">

   </div>
   <div class="test">

   </div>
   <div class="test">

   </div>
</object>
```

in the above `document.querySelectorAll("object .test")` returns a NodeList that contains all divs with `test` class.

Comment: Yes, you need to modify your CSS selector, as per your document structure, the selector here is an example.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your HTML ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d0486o5t/19/ this is similiar to the real one. The page is different  and there are more then 1 ("monitorHW"). I need to reference an item of the page inside the <object> and know at which "monitorHW" it belongs.